# Manipulation and sorting of date strings, location Australia

Tags: string-manipulation, date-and-time

#### Question 1

`DateObject["30.08.90"]` returns `Day: Mon 2 Jun 1997`. How do I get `DateObject["06.02.97"]` to return `Day: 6 Feb 1997` rather than `Day: Mon 2 Jun 1997`?

#### Question 2

How can I convert a list of date strings into a list of date objects that can then be sorted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the the syntax where you specify the order:

```
DateObject[{"06.02.97",{"Day","Month","YearShort"}}]
```

> DateObject[{1997, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -7.]

Comment: Since, as far as I can tell, this option isn't in the `DateObject` documentation, but rather in the `DateList` doc, is this essentially just a shortcut for `DateObject@DateList[{"06.02.97",{"Day","Month","YearShort"}}]`?

Comment: @ThatGravityGuy It is in the documentation starting in M11. What version do you have?

Comment: Ah, well there's my problem.  I work with 10.1.0 and should remember to check the up-to-date online docs.  I was working heavily with 8.0 for about 5 years up until a few months ago.

Answer (score 4):

Since I couldn't find the elegant solution @Carl Woll did, how about this?

```
Quiet@DateObject@StringReplace[
 "06.02.97",
 day__ ~~ "." ~~ mon__ ~~ "." ~~ yr__ :> mon <> "." <> day <> "." <> yr
]
```

> DateObject[{1997, 2, 6}]

It does throw the warning

> DateObject::ambig: "Warning: the interpretation of the string 02.06.97 as a date is ambiguous."

but since you know this is what you want, then you can use the [`Quiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html).

As for your second question, in general you could do

```
DateObject /@ listofdatestrings
```

but if all of the date strings are in the `day.month.year` format as above, then you could use

```
DateObject /@ StringReplace[
 listofdatestrings,
 day__ ~~ "." ~~ mon__ ~~ "." ~~ yr__ :> mon <> "." <> day <> "." <> yr
] // Quiet
```

For example

```
DateObject /@ StringReplace[
 {"06.02.97", "30.08.90"}, 
 day__ ~~ "." ~~ mon__ ~~ "." ~~ yr__ :> mon <> "." <> day <> "." <> yr
] // Quiet
```

> {DateObject[{1997, 2, 6}], DateObject[{1990, 8, 30}]}